# How to conclude that this is a semisimple algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

Let $k$ be a field, $R$ a $k$-algebra and $J$ an ideal of $J$. I have proved that
$$R/J\cong k \oplus \ldots \oplus k$$
which means that $R/J$ is semisimple as a $k$-module. But I want to conclude something more: I want to say that $R/J$ is semisimple as a $k$-algebra. I know about a result that says that an algebra $A$ is semisimple iff the $A$-module $A$ is semisimple. But I think I cannot use this here since I know that $R/J$ is semisimple as a $k$ module, not as a $R/J$ module. Or could I see the field $k$ as an $R/J$-module and therefore conclude that $R/J$ is a semisimple as an $R/J$-module and therefore as an algebra?

**Edit**: This was actually taken from Example 6 in page 57 of Lam's *A first course in noncommutative rings*. There, from the expression $R/J\cong k \oplus \ldots \oplus k$, the author concludes that $R/J$ is semisimple (he doesn't specify if its semisimple as an algebra or as a module) and therefore $\mathfrak{J}(R/J)=0$. We know that $A$ is a semisimple algebra iff $\mathfrak{J}(A)=(0)$. I assume this is the result that the author is using to conclude that $\mathfrak{J}(R/J)=0$, but I do not understand how can he be applying it if we don't know whether $R/J$ is a semisimple algebra.

Comment: When you say $R/J \cong k\oplus\cdots\oplus k$, are the summands on the right side $k$-modules or $R$-modules?

Comment: @MarkSDavis why is that important?

Comment: @kubo I think he suspected you typoed something, because without further context the question was strange.  But your recent edits make it clearer what you were thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot conclude something like that.

Suppose $k$ is a field (as it often is in a lot of contexts).  Then every $k$-module whatsoever is semisimple, even if $R/J$ is not a semisimple algebra.

Concretely, $R=\mathbb R[x]$ and $J=(x^2)$, you have that (as $\mathbb R$ modules) $R/J\cong \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ is a semisimple $\mathbb R$ module, but $R/J$ is not a semisimple algebra because it has nonzero nilpotent elements and is commutative.

---

*After update with reference*

> This was actually taken from Example 6 in page 57 of Lam's *A first course in noncommutative rings*. There, from the expression $R/J\cong k \oplus \ldots \oplus k$, the author concludes that $R/J$ is semisimple (he doesn't specify if its semisimple as an algebra or as a module)

He says $R/J$ is isomorphic to the subset of diagonal matrices of $M_n(k)$ meaning that the ring $R/J$ is isomorphic to the ring $k^n$.  Since $k^n$ is obviously a semisimple ring (in the sense of the Wedderburn-Artin theorem) then so is $R/J$.  One can then say that $R/J$ is a semisimple ring, and that $R/J$ is a semisimple $R/J$ module.  There isn't really any need to talk about $k$ algebras here.

A quotient may very well be isomorphic to some copies of $k$ without being a $k$ algebra.  For example, $\mathbb Z/(3)$ is the field of $3$ elements but $\mathbb Z$ is not an algebra over any field.

Semisimplicity is just a statement about a module over a ring, whether or not that ring is an algebra.   When the ring is an algebra, its modules do come equipped with a special action from $k$, but it doesn't modify what the modules are.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez As we all know, commutative semisimple rings do not have nonzero nilpotents.  I suppose it cannot hurt to reiterate.

Comment: rschwieb and @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez : please check my edit

Comment: @kubo Added based on your comment.  FFR having the passage from Lam's book would have been very helpful up-front.

Comment: You wrote that $R/J \cong k\oplus\cdots\oplus k$, but in fact, the text says that $R/J \cong k\times\cdots\times k$.  This is subtly different but in an important way (which perhaps Lam did not articulate as well as he could have).  This is an isomorphism of *rings*, and $k\times\cdots\times k$ is semisimple by Proposition (3.4) (p. 33).